# Where can I get the Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion Preview?

Tags: download, osx-mountain-lion

Where can I download the [preview version of 10.8](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/)?

I am a developer registered with Apple, but I don't see it in the [developer downloads list](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

Comment: Do we still need this?

Comment: @slhck Not sure. Unfortunately, I don't know whether the preview is still available. If so, I can imagine developers still can use it in case of regressions. I'd keep this for another month or so, until the final release has been distributed more widely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not enough to have a registered developer account. You need to be enrolled in the [Mac developer program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/) to be able to download the developer preview version of Mac OS X 10.8.